# Online voting system in php

Tags: php, session

My project is online voting system in php, requirements is that one user votes, So he will be able to vote only then after 4 years.
Sessions gonna work ?

Comment: Simply: No. The only way is via user registration and storing the voting information in a database with timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Sessions only last as long as the browser remains open.

A better idea would be to post the data to a database with a timestamp. Then, when the user tries to vote again, the most recent vote timestamp by that user is drawn from the database.

If the most recent vote timestamp is > 4 years old, you can then allow the user to post again.

Comment: Hey can you teach me how to do it please

Comment: My magic 8 ball says "outlook not so good"